# I got an email from someone saying "In answer to my question"

Tags: meaning

I got an email from someone saying "In answer to my question" before stating the second line requesting for an update. What does that imply?

Comment: I suspect it implies that the guy does not understand the idiom.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks context, it doesn't say if the sender is a colleague, a client or a complete stranger. The words "in answer to my question" are not difficult to look up in a dictionary, they have a literal meaning.

Answer (score 3):

It implies the person who wrote this email, has posited this question to you already and may be miffed they have received no 'update."

Answer (score 0):

It's also a forum of social engineering. If you can convince someone that they're "ignoring" you,   and get a response,  you've got your first hook set for whatever comes next in your scam. Once you've established a dialogue,  they're likely to continue to respond.